# Magento2 coding style for files and folder names

Tags: magento2, coding-standards

I find that Magento2 core modules don't follow the same style, so I cannot take a reference from there (they're all different).

How should a folder be named:

`PreviouslyBought` or `Previouslybought`? (module name under your package name)

A php file should be:

`PreviouslyBought.php` or `Previouslybought.php`?

A phtml file should be:

`PreviouslyBought.phtml` or `Previouslybought.phtml` or `previouslybought.phtml`?

A javascript file should be:

`PreviouslyBought.js` or `Previouslybought.js` or `previouslybought.js` or `previouslyBought.js`?

A css file should be:

`previously-bought.css` or `previously_bought.css`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL:DR:** The difference between M1 and M2 regarding the file names is that in M2 you can use upper and lowercase as you want in the file names as long as you name the class in the same way.
For templates and js is the same. Just make sure you call the file names exactly how you declared them.

**Long version:**
In M1 this was a problem because of the aliases.
In M1 you had this in config:

```
<models>
    <alias>
        <class>Namespace_Module_Model</class>
    </alias>
</model>
```

and you instantiated a model using

```
    Mage::getModel('alias/some_class_name');
                       |        |
                       |        |
alias defined ---------|    rest of the class name and path 
in config
```

And this was processed by transforming from the second part (after the /)  `_lower letter` into `Upper letter`.
The rest of the letters remained untouched.
And the result is added as a suffix for the value in the `<class>` tag under the alias `<alias>`.

So `alias/some_class_name` became `Namespace_Module_Model_Some_Class_Name` and this class was instantiated.

To get and instance of a class named `Namespace_Module_Model_SomeClass_Name` you had to do it like this:

```
Mage::getModel('alias/someClass_name');
```

(notice the uppercase C).

In M2, the class names are used in their normal form without aliases.
So for example, if you declare in one of your classes as dependency  an instance of `Namespace\Module\Model\SomeClass\Name`, when this is instantiated by the Object Manager it will look for the file that matches the class name without any lower or uppercase transformations.

As a recommendation (it's not mandatory) I would say to use lowercase and underscores in the file names for templates:  `previously_bought.phtml` and `previously_bought.js` and camel case names for php files `PreviouslyBought.php`

Answer (score 2):

Just take file name like, PrevioslyBought,

**As per Magento 2.1 files and folder structure use like below:
Most of the places below files names are used in magento application,**

**Php file Name** like, `PreviouslyBought.php`
All php file name use in CamelCase manner.

**Pthml file name** like,  `previously_bought.phtml`
**All phtml file is used as lower letter with underscore for each separate words.**

**Js file name** like, `previously-bought.js`. **All js file is used as lowercase with dash for each word.**