# Magento 2 - Existing class does not exists

Tags: module, payment-methods, magento-2.0

I'm trying to make a payment module in Magento 2. The module is show in admin Configuration->Sales->Payment method. But when I go to the checkout, only layout renders and the rest of the page is blank. In the system.log, there is a line

```
main.CRITICAL: Class Platiti\Testpayment\Model\Payment\SampleUnimodul_Platba does not exist [] []
```

But the class is there. This is my folder structure in app/code: [image: folder structure]

payment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<payment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Payment:etc/payment.xsd">
    <groups>
        <group id="offline">
            <label>Offline Payment Methods</label>
        </group>
    </groups>
    <methods>
        <method name="sampleunimodul_platba">
            <allow_multiple_address>1</allow_multiple_address>
        </method>
    </methods>
</payment>
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <payment>
            <sampleunimodul_platba>
                <active>1</active>
                <model>Platiti\Testpayment\Model\Payment\SampleUnimodul_Platba</model>
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
                <title>SampleUnimodul_Platba</title>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <group>Offline</group>
            </sampleunimodul_platba>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

SampleUnimodul_Platba.php

```
namespace Platiti\Testpayment\Model\Payment;

class SampleUnimodul_Platba extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod
{

    protected $_code = "sampleunimodul_platba";
    protected $_isOffline = true;

    public function isAvailable(
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null
    ) {
        return parent::isAvailable($quote);
    }
}
```

When I switched to developer mode, this is printed instead of checkout page:

```
Class Platiti\Testpayment\Model\Payment\SampleUnimodul_Platba does not exist
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('Platiti\\Testpay...')
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Platiti\\Testpay...')
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Platiti\\Testpay...')
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Platiti\\Testpay...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-payment/Model/Method/Factory.php(40): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Platiti\\Testpay...', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-payment/Helper/Data.php(138): Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Factory->create('Platiti\\Testpay...')
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-payment/Model/MethodList.php(46): Magento\Payment\Helper\Data->getStoreMethods(1, Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote))
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/PaymentMethodManagement.php(108): Magento\Payment\Model\MethodList->getAvailableMethods(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote))
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php(608): Magento\Quote\Model\PaymentMethodManagement->getList('1')
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php(296): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider->getPaymentMethods()
#10 [internal function]: Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider->getConfig()
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#12 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getConfig', Array, Array)
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/CompositeConfigProvider.php(32): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider\Interceptor->getConfig()
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Onepage.php(91): Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider->getConfig()
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml(26): Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage->getCheckoutConfig()
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/html/v...')
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage), '/var/www/html/v...', Array)
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(279): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/html/v...')
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(657): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(542): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(518): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('checkout.root')
#22 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('checkout.root')
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('checkout.root')
#24 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('checkout.root', true)
#25 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('checkout.root')
#26 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content')
#27 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#28 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#29 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', true)
#30 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('content')
#31 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main')
#32 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#33 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#34 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main', true)
#35 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main')
#36 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns')
#37 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#38 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#39 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns', true)
#40 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('columns')
#41 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content')
#42 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#43 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#44 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content', true)
#45 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.content')
#46 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper')
#47 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#48 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#49 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', true)
#50 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper')
#51 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root')
#52 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#53 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#54 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
#55 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(938): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
#56 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#57 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#58 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(494): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
#59 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(241): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#60 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(162): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#61 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#62 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#63 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#64 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-varnish-...')
#65 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/VarnishPlugin.php(74): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#66 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\VarnishPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#67 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#68 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-builtin-...')
#69 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/BuiltinPlugin.php(67): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#70 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#71 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#72 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#73 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(119): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#74 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#75 /var/www/html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#76 {main}
```

Why can't Magento see the Class? Did I miss something?

Comment: Please remove underscore from your File Name and class name. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130169/magento2-coding-style-for-files-and-folder-names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try emptying your **var/generation/** folder then re-flush cache.

EDIT:

The extra underscore in **`SampleUnimodul_Platba`** should be removed so the class name is **`SampleUnimodulPlatba`**. Rename the php to match.

Comment: Cache already flused, but since I switched to developer mode, the generation folder is not here, as the files are propably  generated only for one use.

Comment: Your error dump makes many references to var/generation. Empty that out anyway just in case.

Comment: Your module class is "SampleUnimodul_Platba".  Try dropping the underscore and renaming the file.

Comment: Just realised in previous comment, I was in /var instead of magento/var. Okay, I deleted the folder and flushed cache, but still no changes.

Comment: Removing the underscore actually did the trick. Please edit your answer so I can mark it as solution.

Comment: Done. Glad it worked out! :)

Comment: Sorry for it, I thought you placed new answer to make it clear, the time was identical